# Is it possible to have two Schema imports in one schema with my own root element

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl

something like....

```
<wsdl:types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">



                <element name="myRootElement">
                <complextype>

<sequence>

<import namespace="namespace1" schemaLocation="xsd/schema1.xsd" />


<import namespace="namespace2" schemaLocation="xsd/schema2.xsd" />
```

Here i want to have my two schemas should i use reference or something else because import and includes are not allowed inside this section
and i want my rootelement for both of them as one....(myRootElement)
what possible ways can i use

```
</sequence>

                </complextype>
                </element>

                </schema>

    </wsdl:types>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `<xs:import>` is not supposed to include some piece of XSD into another XSD.
It is meant to let the XSD processor know that this particular schema may use components
from another (imported) namespace.

If you want to reuse some XSD definitions across different schemas (all of which target the same namespace), you should use `<xs:include>` or `<xs:redefine>` (`<xs:redefine>` allows you to change on the fly a few things defined in the included piece).

But both `<xs:include>` and `<xs:redefine>` can be specified only as direct children of
`<xs:schema>` and only at its beginning.

The fact that `<xs:schema>` is nested in `<wsdl:types>` doesn't change anything here.

Comment: Ok I got your point i wanted to know that if i use two imports and then in third schema i link root elements of both imports then would i   be able to use all the properties of both schema in third one?

Comment: something like...

<wsdl:types>
  <schema xmlns="XMLSchema">
   <import namespace="" />
                        <import namespace="" schemaLocation="" />
  
                
                <element name="myRootElement">
                <complexType>
                <sequence>
                <element ref="external1:UserDetails"></element>
                <element ref="external2:InputParameters"></element>
                
                
                </sequence>
                </complexType>
                
                </element>
                
                </schema>